# Strategies for preventing the insertion of duplicate table rows

Tags: mysql, sql

Scenario:

User A and B executes at the same time `select id from Product where id = ?`, if the there are no results, both create a new product with given ID.

Problem:

This could lead to the creation of duplicate rows.

Question:

What are the possibles strategies to prevent that? I know that I can use compound/unique keys, to guarantee this, but are there any other strategies? Is there any SQL statement to lock query with same parameters?

Comment: Any alternative besides unique constraints?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [unique constraints](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_unique.asp)

```
ALTER TABLE Persons ADD UNIQUE (P_Id)
```

or

```
ALTER TABLE Persons
ADD CONSTRAINT uc_PersonID UNIQUE (P_Id,LastName)
```

That way it would be impossible for a duplicate to be inserted.

Answer (score 0):

Put a `UNIQUE` key on the field in question:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/constraint-primary-key.html